# Runas program as administrator

Tags: windows, command-line, administrator, uac, runas

There is context menu entry on `cmd`, "Run as Administrator", that opens UAC window and launches `cmd` as Administrator.

How can I open a program as Administrator in command line?
I've read about `runas` but it requires `/user` option when context menu entry doesn't require it.

How can I open a program as Administrator in command line without specifying user name? Like context menu entry does.

Comment: @Ramhound `runas /user:%USERNAME%` cmd shows `Incorrect username or password` when I enter correct user password from my USB token.

Comment: Yes, as I said, I can use "Run as Administrator" menu entry with UAC request.

Comment: @Ramhound BTW my user has password associated with security token, and I use this method to login.